# Smallest number of factors to achieve every number up to (and including) x

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Lets say there is a set of numbers, of size n elements. Any of the numbers can be multiplied together, but cannot be used more than once in the same combination. I want to be able to obtain every number, up to and including a particular number x (starting from 0), ONLY as a result of multiplying any of the numbers within the set together.

For example, if x = 20, I want to be able to get 1, 2, 3, ..., 19, 20, with each of those numbers being the result of any combination of the elements being multiplied together within the set.

My question is, how can I determine the smallest possible number of elements (n) within the set to achieve those 20 different combinations; and how can I determine what those numbers are?

Comment: What set of numbers works for $x=20$? Have you tried computing $n$ by hand for other small values of $x$? When you include $x+1$, when do you need a new element?

Comment: @SteveKass I'm wondering if there is an efficient way of calculating these numbers (but more importantly, the minimum value of n) without doing it by hand, especially if you have a large value of x. I suppose it depends on how many prime numbers you have up to x, and if x + 1 is prime, then you need a new element. So I guess n must be greater than the number of primes up to x, but I'm not sure about the non-primes.

Comment: Try some examples!  Primes alone won't do the job, you can't get $4$ if you only have $2$.

Comment: So is there no algorithm that can do the job then?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to include $1$ as the only way to get it would be to have it already in the set.

Let's now say $p$ is a prime number less or equal than $x$. You will need to include $p$ because this is the only way to have it included in the set. If now $p^2\le x$, you will need to include $p^2$, because the only way to have $p^2$ is if it is included in the set. (You cannot have it as $p\cdot p$ because you have disallowed repetition.) However, now you've included $p^2$, if it happens that $p^3\le x$, you can make $p^3=p\cdot p^2$. However, if you don't include $p^3$, and if $p^4\le x$, you must include $p^4$ etc.

Needless to say, if we have such a set that enables us to see every *prime power* not greater than $x$ as a product, then every other composite number not greater than $x$ can also be seen as a product - simply break it up as a product of prime powers and make out those prime powers as products.

This suggests the following strategy:

1. Solve a simpler problem: given $n$, find the smallest subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ so that every number from $1$ to $n$ is a *sum* of the different numbers from that subset. This is because, as we *multiply* prime powers, we *add* their exponents.
2. Use the solution of (1) above for every prime number $p\le x$, taking $n=\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor$ - the highest power of $p$ not larger than $x$.
3. At the end, don't forget to add number $1$ to the set.

So, for example, for $x=20$, you have primes $2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19$ and the highest powers of those not exceeding $20$ are $4,2,1,1,1,1,1,1$ respectively, so:

- For prime $p=2$ we have seen we need to choose three numbers (either $2^1, 2^2, 2^3$ or $2^1,2^2,2^4$)
- For prime $p=3$ we have to choose two numbers ($3^1, 3^2$)
- For other primes, we have to choose them.

The set will end up being either $\{1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,13,17,19\}$ or $\{1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11,13,16,17,19\}$

---

Of course, we have not solved the problem 1 above, but it looks plausible that, if you choose the numbers that are themselves powers of $2$ you will be able to make any number as a sum of those. (Let's say $n=15$ and you can choose numbers $1,2,4,8$ and write every number from $1$ to $15$ as a sum of those - using the binary representation.)

This can be shown to be the minimum. Note if $n$ is given, take the numbers $1,2,2^2,2^3,\ldots,2^k$ so that $2^{k+1}>n\ge 2^k$. There are $k+1$ of those numbers, and again recalling binary representation, you can make up any number up to not just $n$ but $2^{k+1}-1\ge n$ as a sum of some of those numbers. However, if you took fewer ($k$) numbers, you cannot possibly make up all the sums up to $n$ because the number of (nonempty) sums of $k$ numbers is up to $2^k-1<n$. As we have seen before, this may not be the *only* minimum ($n=4$ admits the minimum $\{1,2,3\}$ as well as $\{1,2,4\}$) but it is certainly one of the minima.

---

**Summary** Given $x$, find all prime numbers not bigger than $x$. For each such prime number $p$ find the highest degree $n=\lfloor\log_p(x)\rfloor$ such that $p^n\le x$. Take the set of numbers $1,2,2^2\ldots,2^k\le n\lt 2^{k+1}$ (i.e. $k=\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$). Your set will now consist of:

- The number $1$, and
- All the sets $\{p, p^2, p^{2^2},\ldots, p^{2^k}\}$ for all those prime $p$'s

Comment: If you allow an empty product to have value $1$, then you wouldn't need $1$.